# Unreachable statement in switch in android Content Provider

Tags: android

So I'm getting an unreachable statement in the following switch statement. I can't figure out why this is happening, any help would be much appreciated.

```
@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = psHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int delCount = 0;
    return 0;
    switch (URI_MATCHER.match(uri)) {
        case PRODUCT_LIST:
            // THE LINE BELOW IS UNREACHABLE
            delCount = db.delete(TABLE_NAME_PRODUCTS, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;
        case PRODUCT_ID:
            String idStr = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            String where = PSContract.Products.ID_COLUMN + " = " + idStr;
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                where += " AND " + selection;
            }
            delCount = db.delete(TABLE_NAME_PRODUCTS, where, selectionArgs);
            break;
        case SUPPLIER_LIST:
            delCount = db.delete(TABLE_NAME_SUPPLIERS, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;
        case SUPPLIER_ID:
            String idStr2 = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            String where2 = PSContract.Products.ID_COLUMN + " = " + idStr2;
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                where2 += " AND " + selection;
            }
            delCount = db.delete(TABLE_NAME_SUPPLIERS, where2, selectionArgs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
    }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return delCount;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You're returning 0 right before the switch.  There is no way that the switch can be reached if you return from the method right before, so the error is generated.

Answer (score 1):

Under int delCount = 0 you are returning 0 which is going end the function call. Since that return is in a place where it will happen 100% of the time nothing below it will ever execute. Looks like a typo to me.